# Impala regexp_like query returning null when regexp_like and regexp_extract works fine

Tags: regex, hadoop, etl, impala

I need to extract the numbers form a string in a column using **regex_extract**. I'm using Impala over a external Table.

I have already checked the regular expression, and to test it, I also used **regexp_like** and **regexp_replace**. Both of them worked just perfect.

Here is the query:

```
select 
    sucursal,
    regexp_like(sucursal,'^[0-9]{1,3}') as match,
    regexp_extract(sucursal,'^[0-9]{1,3}',1) as CodSucusal,
    regexp_replace(sucursal,'^[0-9]{1,3}','lala') as RepCodSucusal
from jdv.stg_devoluciones limit 5;
```

here is the results:

```
+-------------------+-------+------------+--------------------+
| sucursal          | match | codsucusal | repcodsucusal      |
+-------------------+-------+------------+--------------------+
| 124 NAVOJOA       | true  |            | lala NAVOJOA       |
| 73 BOCA DEL RIO   | true  |            | lala BOCA DEL RIO  |
| 964 JIUTEPEC      | true  |            | lala JIUTEPEC      |
| 456 TEQUISQUIAPAN | true  |            | lala TEQUISQUIAPAN |
| 212 LANDIN        | true  |            | lala LANDIN        |
+-------------------+-------+------------+--------------------+
```

**codsucursal** should be the sucursal number but **regexp_extract** is returning **null** instead

Expected results:

```
+-------------------+-------+------------+--------------------+
| sucursal          | match | codsucusal | repcodsucusal      |
+-------------------+-------+------------+--------------------+
| 124 NAVOJOA       | true  |   124      | lala NAVOJOA       |
| 73 BOCA DEL RIO   | true  |   73       | lala BOCA DEL RIO  |
| 964 JIUTEPEC      | true  |   964      | lala JIUTEPEC      |
| 456 TEQUISQUIAPAN | true  |   456      | lala TEQUISQUIAPAN |
| 212 LANDIN        | true  |   212      | lala LANDIN        |
+-------------------+-------+------------+--------------------+
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Shouldn't it be `regexp_extract(sucursal,'^[0-9]{1,3}', 0) as CodSucusal`? The index must be `0`.

Comment: Thanks, but I have already tried. In impala you need three parameters. The last one is the index of the regex group that needs to be extracted in case there are many matches.

Comment: So, did you try `0`?

Comment: Genius. That worked just perfect! Thxs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Impala `regexp_extract` function](https://www.cloudera.com/documentation/enterprise/5-9-x/topics/impala_string_functions.html) takes the index of a capturing group or `0` for the whole match as the third argument.

> **`regexp_extract(string subject, string pattern, int index)`**
>   **Purpose**: Returns the specified () group from a string based on a regular expression pattern. Group 0 refers to the entire extracted string, while group 1, 2, and so on refers to the first, second, and so on `(...)` portion.

As your regex - `^[0-9]{1,3}` - has no capturing groups defined in it you should use `0` as the third argument to refer to the whole match value:

```
regexp_extract(sucursal,'^[0-9]{1,3}', 0) as CodSucusal
```